# Including awk in shell script makes the output empty?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I made a shell script that I can to use make my playlists for MPD. I got it to write songs by folder and artist like I wanted to however when I try to use awk to remove duplicates at the end of the script the output becomes empty.

Heres the script:

```
(
mpc search artist 'Black Coast' &&
mpc search artist 'ASTR' &&
ls ~/music/HDD/Chill | awk '$0="HDD/Chill/"$0'
) | tee testi.txt;
awk '!v[$0]++' testi.txt | tee testi.txt
```

The awk above prefixes a string correctly however if I add the awk below the output is a empty file. The line however works when out of the script file.

EDIT: It works with

```
(
mpc search artist 'Black Coast' &&
mpc search artist 'ASTR' &&
ls ~/music/HDD/Chill | awk '$0="HDD/Chill/"$0'
) | awk '!v[$0]++' | tee testi.txt
```

So I quess the question changed to why does the example above not work?

Comment: why the two `tee`s? why do you have a temporary file?

Comment: If you have GNU awk, you can do in-place editing. And there's sponge from moreutils: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207921/70524

Answer (score 0):

You're writing to the same file you're reading. Never do that as the shell could write it before reading it. You want SOMETHING like this (untested):

```
(awk '!v[$0]++' testi.txt | tee tmp.txt) && mv tmp.txt testi.txt
```

Comment: So it's basically asynchronous?

Comment: idk if that's the term I'd choose for it but it's up to the shell to decide which order to read vs write when you're reading and writing the same file with the same command. Google is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is that your input and output files are the same. This will result in it being truncated for writing before awk can read from it.

I would suggest doing this:

```
(
    mpc search artist 'Black Coast' &&
    mpc search artist 'ASTR' &&
    ls ~/music/HDD/Chill | awk '$0="HDD/Chill/"$0'
) | awk '!v[$0]++' | tee testi.txt
```

That way, the output file is only touched once.

Also, I don't really like the look of the `ls` line - I'd suggest using something like this:

```
( cd ~/music && printf '%s\n' HDD/Chill/* )
```

This creates an extra subshell but the outer one isn't needed, so you could change your command to this:

```
{
    mpc search artist 'Black Coast' &&
    mpc search artist 'ASTR' &&
    ( cd ~/music && printf '%s\n' HDD/Chill/* )
} | awk '!v[$0]++' | tee testi.txt
```

This will fail if your filenames contain newlines (but then again, so would your original approach).

Comment: Is there any other benefit to that other than being easier to copy (incase I wanted more folders)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean about being easier to copy but I guess you're asking about my usage of `printf`. Firstly, it's a good idea to avoid using `ls` in scripts - in this case it's not much of a problem but it's a bad habit to get into. Also this way avoids the repetition of the directory name.

Comment: What I meant by easier to copy was the repetition of the directory name. I'm not all that concerned with my use of ls but I'll switch to yours just for avoiding repetition and it looking cleaner overall.